# Group custom post listing in admin section

Tags: query, groupby

I am trying to alter the listing results in the admin section for a custom post type.

I am using Custom Post Type UI plugin to create custom post types and data is saved with meta keys. The listing needs to be grouped based on the meta value. For example this is my data listing in a normal view. All data are saved as post meta values.

```
Name, Reg ID, Location, Date Clocked In / Out
Tom, 123, City A, 2017-03-01 00:00:00
Tom, 123, City A, 2017-03-01 08:00:00
Mark, 321, City B, 2017-03-01 00:00:00
Mark, 321, City B, 2017-03-01 08:00:00
Mark, 321, City B, 2017-03-02 00:00:00
Mark, 321, City B, 2017-03-02 08:00:00
```

There is another section which needs to show the same set of data with some calculation of how long they have worked. The intended listing is:

```
Name, Reg ID, Location, Date, Total Work Time
Tom, 123, City A, 2017-03-01, 8 hours
Mark, 321, City B, 2017-03-01, 8 hours
Mark, 321, City B, 2017-03-02, 8 hours
```

I intend to group the meta value by day, registration id and location. And then from there once the list is returned, the total work time can be calculated during the post listing.

For a front-end display, I don't see any issue doing this. But for the listing in the admin section, I am having trouble to get this work.

From my understanding, the list in admin section is using the WP_List_Table class. It seems like I need to get the results first from the query results and then modify the results list before it goes into the loop in WP_List_Table.

I read that queries should be modified in **parse_query** or **pre_get_posts** but it looks like I need to process the query results which is after these hooks.

I am also unable to find solutions on modifying queries to group by multiple meta keys.

Can this be achieved from hooks and filters?

Comment: did you ask this question in the ACF Forums?

Comment: Nope, as this is not dependent on ACF.

Comment: It actually is.  I don't know what type of fields you created within the plugin or if you used actual meta fields.  ANd  that makes it difficult to make a filter.  Also. Acf May have a function or hook we could use.  I'm not trying to be difficult.  Just need more info and didn't want to reinvent the proverbial wheel

Comment: No worries, I understand where you're coming from. The meta values are actually inserted using WordPress update_post_meta function. I only use ACF to create a custom post type. Everything else is using wordpress in built function. Will there be a filter that I can use in this case?

Comment: I'm trying to help here but acf doesn't create post types,  only fields.   Can you post your field create codes?

Comment: I must have been drunk. The plugin I used was Custom Post Type UI to create the custom post. ACF wasn't used in this project. My apologies for the confusion. I will edit the original post.

Comment: Ha.  I will look again when I'm at a computer.

Comment: Again, my apologies for the confusion